# CLLocationManagerDelegate not catching events

Tags: ios, swift

first of all, i'm new to iOS development, so please don't explain to me with objective-c examples.

my question is:
**i've made this class:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class BeaconRadar: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var manager : CLLocationManager!
    var region  : CLBeaconRegion!

    var seenError           = false
    var locationFixAchieved = false
    var locationStatus      = "Not Started"

    init() {
        super.init()

        var major   = CLBeaconMajorValue( 10 )
        var uuid    = NSUUID( UUIDString: "E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0" )
        var id      = "test"

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        region  = CLBeaconRegion( proximityUUID: uuid, major: major, identifier: id )

        manager.delegate        = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: AnyObject[], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion! ){

        if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
            locationFixAchieved = true

            println(beacons)

        }

    }

    // If failed
    func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager!, rangingBeaconsDidFailForRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!, withError error: NSError!){

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        if (error) {
            if (seenError == false) {
                seenError = true
                println("Error getting location")
            }
        }
    }

    //  // authorization status
    func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
        println("2")
        var shouldIAllow = false

        switch status {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
                locationStatus = "Restricted Access"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
                locationStatus = "User denied access"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
                locationStatus = "Status not determined"
            default:
                locationStatus = "Allowed Access"
                shouldIAllow = true
        }

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
        if (shouldIAllow == true) {
            println("Location Allowed")
            // Start location services
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            println("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
        }
    }
}
```

**and my viewController is:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var location = BeaconRadar()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

i'm expecting to get one of the messages in the implemantation func for the authorization status. ( the last one in BeaconRadar). but i'm getting nothing.

if i'll implement all this methods in the viewController instead of in new class 
(i.e:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
.....
}
```

then it will work just fine...

**Am i missing something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your `BeaconRadar` instance as a local variable inside `viewDidLoad`, so as soon as this function exits, the BeaconRadar instance is released.

You should move the BeaconRegion variable out of the function -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let location = BeaconRadar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```